# im not getting image uri .....the image stored in firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

```
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
Uri image=uri;
Toast.makeText(viewpgdetails.this, "image uri="+image , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

Toast.makeText(viewpgdetails.this, "failed to get image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Handle any errors
            }
        });
        // [END download_full_example]
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please describe your issue with a short paragraph and a summary of what you have tried before in addition to the code snippet you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear which type of URI you want, so I'll include both versions.

### Google Storage URI

This is not very useful outside of a Google APIs.

This will be in the format: `gs://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/path/to/file.png`

To get this value, you would use the following code:

```
String storageUri = storage.getReference('path/to/file.png').toString();
```

In the question's code, you would use:

```
StorageReference fileRef = storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png")
fileRef.getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
        Toast.makeText(viewpgdetails.this, "image uri: " + fileRef.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Use the bytes to display the image
      }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        Toast.makeText(viewpgdetails.this, "failed to get image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Handle any errors
      }
    });
```

### HTTPS Resource URL

This URL would be used if you wanted to include the image in a web page or link to it in an email.

This will be in the format: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/o/path%2Fto%2Ffile.png?alt=media&token=ACCESS_TOKEN`

Because this URL uses an access token issued by the server, it must be requested and returned to the client asynchronously. This is achieved with the following code:

```
Task<Uri> getDownloadUrlTask = storage.getReference('path/to/file.png').getDownloadUrl();
```

In the question's code, you would use:

```
StorageReference fileRef = storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png")
fileRef.getDownloadUrl()
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Uri downloadUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(viewpgdetails.this, "image url: " + downloadUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Use URL for internal web page, etc.
      }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        Toast.makeText(viewpgdetails.this, "failed to get image url", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Handle any errors
      }
    });
```

**Note:** If you want both the HTTPS URL and the file as a byte array, they would have to be requested as seperate Tasks using both `getBytes()` and `getDownloadUrl()`.

### See also

- [Cloud Storage for Android Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start)
- [StorageReference API Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html)